# JWT Authentication - Do I need Refresh Tokens?

Tags: c#, authentication, jwt, claims-based-identity, refresh-token

I have a .Net Core API that provides basic Bearer Authorization using a symmetric key to generate a JWT on a successful login. It runs inside a Docker Container, and doesn't maintain state. Let's call this *API 1*

This endpoint is called by a mobile application `POST /Authenticate`. A 3rd party develops and maintains this mobile app.

The business logic for this endpoint is:

1. send the username + password provided in the request over to another REST API on our network (maintained by another team). We'll call this *API 2*.
2. *API 2* then takes that UN/PW and checks against a database to validate that the credentials are correct
3. If valid, *API 2* sends over an access token (JWT) and a refresh token over to *API 1*, where essentially, *API 1* will parse the JWT for a unique User Id (we use this unique User Id across all apps in the organization). *API 1* does nothing with the refresh token.
4. If *API 1* can parse this User Id successfully, It will then generate a *new* JWT, using a SymmetricSecurityKey, and adding that Parsed User ID as a Claim.

So then, this JWT is returned to the Native App client, and has an expiry of 60 minutes (although, I've seen around that 15 minutes is more common..). This token needs to be included in each protected resource on my API using an authorization header `Authorization: Bearer xyz123etc`

**SO**, in efforts to keep *API 1* scalable and stateless, and not need to add tables to *API 1*'s backend database for storing Refresh Tokens, am I okay not offering a 'Refresh' token for *API 1*?

My thought is, the mobile app should be able to Log In once, store the UN/PW used in SharedPreferences/NSUserDefaults, and if the client ever gets a 401 unauthorized from *API 1*, maybe on `GET /SomeProtectedResource`, the client will just need to make another call to `POST Authenticate` to get a new JWT from *API 2*, and retry calling `GET /SomeProtectedResource`

Am I flawed here? I don't see a need to offer a 'Refresh Token' endpoint

Comment: I can't directly answer the question but why your API is able to parse JWT from API2? If I understand it right it means that your API has the same security key as other API and that's not right. Only the issuer should be able to decrypt the token.

Comment: @Michalides The JWT received from API2 is just a HMAC token, and it doesnt contain any encrypted data. For example, I'm able to paste the token using  https://jwt.io, where I can then view the 'UserId' claim from within the payload of the JWT.